# Proper phrasing of proof on independence and identical distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, proof-writing, random-variables, independence

I'm thinking of a probability/statistics proof about independence and identical distribution, but I don't know the proper way to phrase it mathematically. The proposition is that, if the observations/elements of a sample / set / random variable $X$ are i.i.d. with respect to each other, and the observations/elements of a sample / set / random variable $Y$ are i.i.d. with respect to each other, then that does **not** necessarily mean that the observations/elements of each of the two samples / sets / random variables are i.i.d. with respect to each other. And the proof would then simply be assuming that the observations/elements of a sample / set / random variable $X = Z$ are i.i.d., and that then if we let $Y = Z$, then clearly $Z$ is not i.i.d. to itself. What is the correct way to phrase this?

Furthermore, this property seems very similar to linearity / closure under addition, but not exactly the same, so I'm not sure what it should be called or what property it exactly is. What is this property called (if not, say, linearity)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say that there is some random variable $Z$ such that $X = Z$ and $Y = Z$ is simply to say that $X$ and $Y$ are identical; that is, $X = Y$. What you can imagine is that we randomly generate a number to determine the value of $X$, then we set $Y$ equal to the very same number. As you point out, this should mean that $X$ and $Y$ are *not* independent, because if we know $X$ then we know exactly the value of $Y$.

Your proof might proceed as follows. Consider a sequence of i.i.d. random variables $Z_1, \dotsc, Z_n$ where each $Z_i$ takes value $0$ with probability $1/2$ and value $1$ with probability $1/2$. Set $X_i = Z_i$ and $Y_i = Z_i$. Then $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$ is an i.i.d. sequence (since it's the same sequence as the sequence of $Z_i$'s), and so is $Y_1, \dotsc, Y_n$. However,
$$ X_1, \dotsc, X_n, Y_1, \dotsc, Y_n $$
is not a collection of independent random variables, since for example $X_1$ is not independent of $Y_1$. To see this, we can observe that
$$ P(X_1 = 1 \text{ and } Y_1 = 1) = P(X_1 = 1) = \frac 1 2 $$
is not equal to
$$ P(X_1 = 1) \, P(Y_1 = 1) = \frac 1 4 . $$

Comment: As far as I know, this "property" you mentioned does not have any name, but I would not really consider it a property of random variables. A statement like closure under addition of real numbers says, "if $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, then $x+y$ is one as well." On the other hand, our statement says, "if $\{ X_1, \dotsc, X_n \}$ and $\{ Y_1, \dotsc, Y_n \}$ are collections of i.i.d. random variables, then their union is *not necessarily* a collection of i.i.d. random variables." Notice that it has no affirmative conclusion.

Comment: I just realised that my "proof" outline only proves that it is true for $X = Y$; but it says nothing about the case where $X \not= Y$.

Comment: And I don't even think this case makes sense, since, if we have that $X = Y$, then do we really have two random variables? So I think it's nonsensical from the beginning.

Comment: Furthermore, it doesn't even make sense to talk about observations themselves being i.i.d., since i.i.d. is a property of random variables – not observations.

Comment: You're right that if $Y = X$, then these two letters represent the same random variable. You might want to check the textbook you're using to see how it defines an "observation," because in some statistical literature, an *observation* is by definition a random variable. Usually, an observation is part of a *random sample*, which is a collection of i.i.d. random variables.